# Why was a question about the origin and meaning of a phrase closed because the origin is known?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, close-reasons, question-closure

**Note: The question in question has been reopened.**

The question ['What’s the origin/meaning of “from belt buckle to shoe sole”?'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/546392/what-s-the-origin-meaning-of-from-belt-buckle-to-shoe-sole) was closed because

> Mr Biden consistently gives the origin - his uncle. The absence of any other source indicates that the phrase is part of an idiolect.

As noted in a closure comment subsequently supported by at least three other closers.

The given reason for closing a question asking about origins and meaning of a phrase is *prima facie* nonsensical, and seems to be trolling the hapless asker, who has, unsurprisingly, not been seen since.

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: It appears that the question was not actually closed, but an upvoted comment suggests to do so.

Comment: @user121863 the question was closed at some point based on [its timeline](https://english.stackexchange.com/posts/546392/timeline)

Comment: @AndrewT. - how did you get to the timeline from the original question?

Comment: @user121863 the timeline is the "clock" icon under the "bookmark" icon and "downvote" button. It's only available on the full web site though, not mobile web nor the apps.